# Cheap online graduate math courses

Tags: soft-question, advice

I am an undergraduate math major. I want to have some math graduate courses on my transcript. I can't do this at my university. Are there online graduate math courses that I can take and receive a certificate  after I complete the course successfully. I don't want a full degree, I just want some graduate courses. I searched Google, but I couldn't find any. It  is better if the courses are cheap. Thank you

Comment: Not only this question is offtopic here, the title sounds pretty much as if you were _offering_ courses in math  - which is absolutely not allowed.

Comment: @JanDvorak Where should I ask this question on stack exchange ? I also don't get the second part of your comment.

Comment: I think the title is appropriate given the content of the question, although Jan Dvorak may be right that the question itself is off-topic.

Comment: @JanDvorak IWhat do you mean by: "I am offering courses" ? I am a student as I meantioned, and you should not assume something else. I see no reason to assume that I am lying.

Comment: @TrevorWilson well, it does sound like a spam post title, doesn't it?

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, and it isn't.  So what that means is that we should be more careful about assuming something is spam just from the title.

Comment: @JanDvorak Am I supposed to prove that I am a student , before posting questions online ???? I really don't understand why you said: "as if you were offering courses in math - which is absolutely not allowed."

Comment: I don't think Jan Dvorak's comment means he doubts you are not a student, or thinks that you are selling something.  He was just asserting that the title suggested this, which would only make it a bad title.  I don't know why he said the "absolutely not allowed" bit, which is clearly an irrelevant warning given the actual content of your question.

Comment: @TrevorWilson OK. No problem, now lets discuss the question and forget about math exchange rules (I am not interested in them). Do you have any idea about such online courses ? Thank you a lot

Comment: I've never heard of any online graduate courses in math, but maybe other people have (or can say definitively that they don't exist.)

Comment: @TrevorWilson I already checked coursera, they have few advanced math courses, and even when they have the courses are usually small. See: https://www.coursera.org/course/functionalanalysis

Comment: Surely the first thing to decide is what part of maths you actually want to learn about...

Comment: @fretty What do you mean ?

Answer (score 5):

The University of Washington applied math program [offers](http://www.amathonline.uw.edu/) an online graduate masters degree. I know some who have completed it. There are constantly courses in PDEs, complex variables, and linear algebra. I know in the past there has been at least one course in Analysis (I am not sure if it was more applied or an introduction to real analysis). You may be looking more for pure math courses, but I know that UW's applied math program is a top-ranked program, so you will be getting a quality education if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am unable to find the cost of the online course. This is unfortunately an important factor for me

Comment: @AMr The courses are $900 a credit hour as seen [here](http://www.amathonline.uw.edu/fees/fees.asp). This can be cheap or expensive depending on what you are used to paying for school. [Here](http://www.amathonline.uw.edu/fees/financial.asp) it says you are not eligible for stipends, but you may be eligible for other financial aid. Luckily since you want to study math there are a ton of grants and scholarships available, see [here](http://www.scholarships.com/financial-aid/college-scholarships/scholarships-by-major/math-scholarships/) for a list. I know many who have received these. Good luck!

Comment: 900 dollars is actually expensive for me, I was looking for something close to being free. Coursera has courses that require a payment of $50. I was looking for something like that. I am also not sure I will be eligible for financial aid. I just want to take some graduate courses not a full degree.

Comment: Finally, thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

There is a website called [www.saylor.org](http://www.saylor.org) its completely free and they designed the mathematics portion as if you were in a university. It seems pretty good. Check it out.

Comment: It seems great. Does this organization give a certificate ?!!

Comment: Yes they let give you a downloadable certificate once your done with the course and passed the final.

Comment: @user60887 Have you taken any of these courses? These courses seem to be medium-high level undergraduate courses.

Comment: @JjeremyUpsal I agree with you. They don't like they are graduate courses, but your answer is appreciated user60887 (better than nothing :) )

Comment: I've have used to some of their material as a reference and these are pretty much standard level undergraduate  courses and some graduate level courses. Its free so I say there is nothing to lose if use this website.

Comment: I don't see any graduate level mathematics courses on that site. Am I missing something?

Comment: They might have changed a lot in the 8 years since this question was posed, but all I can see right now are advanced high-school level to first year University level courses.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an aggregate of courses (known as MOOCs - Massive Open Online Courses) on [this site](https://www.class-central.com/subject/maths) including some [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) courses which I believe offer verified certification.

Pulling a statement right from the FAQ of *Class Central*:

> Some courses offer a ‘*Statement of Accomplishment*’ (sometimes with ‘Distinction’), but these are issued in the name of the MOOC provider, with only mention of the professor and university.  Recently, Coursera has offered a ‘Signature Track’, which, for a fee, verifies that the student has actually completed the course. Note that although MOOCs generally **do not result in college credit**, many individuals who have completed MOOCs list them as training experiences on their profiles or resumes.

[emphasis mine]

Comment: I already checked coursera, I don't believe they have any graduate courses. I also don't want to count these courses for credit, I just want them to be on my CV for the application comittee to see. Wouldn't the application comittee of a grad school appreciate these courses on my CV ?

Comment: The best people to ask that would be people on the graduate school committee at your school. Assuming you have some kind of personal tutor/supervisor in your department, they should know if doing such courses will bolster your CV or be a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Athabasca University's website http://www.athabascau.ca/course/ug_subject/im.php. It seems to offer correspondence courses on upper-year undergrad-level math courses. Not sure about grad-level math courses though.

Comment: The problem is that it's not graduate. Thank you anyways